# Error: Missing positive glob

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, pug

The above message appears everytime the gulp gets to the 'markup' function.

Here is my gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    autoPrefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    jade = require('gulp-jade'),
    liveReload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    sourceMaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    ts = require('gulp-typescript'),
    tsLint = require('gulp-tslint'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass');

// Configuration
var config = {
    js: 'public/_assets/frontend/js',
    css: 'public/_assets/frontend/css',
    fonts: 'public/_assets/frontend/fonts',
    images: 'public/_assets/frontend/img',
    markup: 'public/'
};

// Javascript
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    var tsResult = gulp.src(['src/ts/*.ts', 'src/ts/**/*.ts'])
        .pipe(tsLint())
        .pipe(ts({
            noImplicitAny: true
        }));

        tsResult.js
            .pipe(gulp.dest(config.js))
            .pipe(liveReload());
});

// Sass
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src(['src/sass/*.scss', 'src/sass/**/*.scss'])
        .pipe(watch(['src/sass/*.scss', 'src/sass/**/*.scss']))
        .pipe(sourceMaps.init())
        .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoPrefixer({
            browsers: ['last 3 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(sourceMaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.css))
        .pipe(liveReload());
});

// jade
gulp.task('markup', function() {
    return gulp.src([['src/**/*.jade', 'src/**/_*.jade']])
        .pipe(jade({
            pretty: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.markup))
        .pipe(liveReload());
});

// Images
gulp.task('images', function() {
    return gulp.src(['src/images/**/*.*', 'src/images/*.*'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.images));
});

// Watch
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    liveReload.listen();
    gulp.watch(['src/ts/*.ts', 'src/ts/**/*.ts'], ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch(['src/sass/*.scss', 'src/sass/**/*.scss'], ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(['src/*.jade', 'src/**/*.jade'], ['markup']);
});

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.start('sass', 'scripts', 'markup', 'images', 'watch');
});

// Dist Scripts
gulp.task('distScripts', function() {
    return gulp.src(['src/ts/plugins/**/*', 'src/ts/*.js'], { "base" : "./src/ts" })
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.js));
});

// Dist Styles
gulp.task('distStyles', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/sass/**/*.css', { "base" : "./src/sass" })
        .pipe(autoPrefixer({
            browsers: ['last 3 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.css));
});

// Dist Fonts
gulp.task('distFonts', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/fonts/**/*', { "base" : "./src/fonts" })
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.fonts));
});


// Dist
gulp.task('dist', function() {
    gulp.start('distScripts', 'distStyles', 'images', 'distFonts');
});
```

Here is the message I get when I run 'gulp':

```
(node:9460) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version. [00:39:30] Using gulpfile D:\Projects\FrontEnd\Project\gulpfile.js [00:39:30] Starting 'default'... [00:39:30] Starting 'sass'... [00:39:30] Starting 'scripts'... [00:39:30] Finished 'scripts' after 4.66 ms [00:39:30] Starting 'markup'... [00:39:30] 'markup' errored after 86 μs [00:39:30] Error: Missing positive glob
    at Object.gs.create (D:\Projects\FrontEnd\Project\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\glob-stream\index.js:73:39)
    at Gulp.src (D:\Projects\FrontEnd\Project\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\lib\src\index.js:33:23)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\FrontEnd\Project\gulpfile.js:50:14)
    at module.exports (D:\Projects\FrontEnd\Project\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (D:\Projects\FrontEnd\Project\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (D:\Projects\FrontEnd\Project\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
    at D:\Projects\FrontEnd\Project\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:279:18
    at finish (D:\Projects\FrontEnd\Project\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:21:8)
    at module.exports (D:\Projects\FrontEnd\Project\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:60:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (D:\Projects\FrontEnd\Project\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3) [00:39:30] Finished 'default' after 42 ms
```

Any idea why? Seems like it happens when rendering Jade... All the dependencies are installed of course.

Comment: Seems like you are using an array inside an array to read your files with gulp.src(). It should be: gulp.src(['src/**/*.jade', 'src/**/_*.jade']) and not: gulp.src([['src/**/*.jade', 'src/**/_*.jade']])

Comment: Please post this as an answer... So this worked, but for some reason the live reload does not refresh the page when I update a page... (I'm using a python server)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like you are using an multidimensional array `[["item1","item2"]]`. To read your files with `gulp.src()` you should use a string like `'path/to/*.jade'` or an simple onedimensional array like `["path/to/first/*.jade", "path/to/second/glob/**/*.jade"]`.

In your case the **JADE-Task should look like this:**

```
// jade
gulp.task('markup', function() {
    return gulp.src(['src/**/*.jade', 'src/**/_*.jade'])
        .pipe(jade({
            pretty: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.markup))
        .pipe(liveReload());
});
```

**Regarding your watch-task:**

You should call your livereload in an own task as a callback of your watch-task. It is also recommended to define the root path of your destination folder, as an argument option in the `liveReload()` object.

```
// Watch
gulp.task('livereload', function() {
    return gulp.src('./dist')
       .pipe(
          liveReload({
             start: true,
             basePath: 'path/to/destination'
          })
       );
});
gulp.task('watch', ['livereload'], function() {
    liveReload.listen()
    gulp.watch(['src/ts/*.ts', 'src/ts/**/*.ts'], ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch(['src/sass/*.scss', 'src/sass/**/*.scss'], ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(['src/*.jade', 'src/**/*.jade'], ['markup']);
});
```

Do not forget to start your watch-task in your default-task

```
// Dist
gulp.task('dist', ['watch'], function() {
    gulp.start('distScripts', 'distStyles', 'images', 'distFonts');
});
```

Comment: Now it's stuck on "Starting 'livereload'..."

Comment: Sorry i did something wrong, changed the task on how i use it with `'gulp-webserver'` take a look into my default template app: https://github.com/pure180/DefaultTemplate/blob/master/gulpfile.js
It's a bit outdated but it works perfect for me.